# Wired Keyboard keeps disconnecting in MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a MacBook Pro 14" M2 Pro Chip and using a USB-C to USB adapter, I have connected my USB Wired Keyboard to it. But, the keyboard stops working sometimes. It does not randomly stop working - it disconnects when I have stopped working on the keyboard for some time.

I just plug the adapter out and back into the MacBook and the keyboard then works normally (for a while before this happens again). It is not a big issue but it is inconvenient.

How can I fix this? If it matters, I have a wireless Bluetooth mouse, but it does not disconnect (even after inactivity).

Thanks

Comment: Check two items: 1) make sure the keyboard with a different machine ***without*** the adapter/hub and 2) make sure your Mac isn’t going to sleep during this period.

Comment: @Allan Hi, The keyboard works alright - I have previously used the same keyboard for some time with a different MacBook (without any adapters - the MacBook had a USB port inbuilt). Also, the Mac isn't going to sleep during the period.

Comment: It could then potentially be the adapter not maintaining a good connection. Try a USB hub instead.

Comment: @Allan That might be possible. I will check. Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using the Moonlander keyboard and a Mac Mini. But every morning I have to plug the cable out of the moonlander and plug it back in for it to work on the mac. On my windows machine, it works perfectly everytime day after day. I had the same setup on my previous non M2 mac and it worked fine on it as well. Its the M2 that I am having issues with.

Comment: @Yathi I don't know if you have fixed the issue yet. But for future viewers, I changed the USB Hub (bought a newer one) and it works fine now.

Comment: @MangoPizza: I'll try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the USB Hub and it works fine now. The adapter was not maintaining a good connection. Thanks to @Allan.